# PHP SOAP extension install

Tags: php, soap, web-hosting

I have a error problem to host my site. Error is "SOAP extension not installed on your server, please talk to your hosting company and they will install it for you."

I host my site in ipage.com and ask the guys there but they told me "I am sorry say that the SOAP extension is not supported on our server."

ipage use php 5.3 version. only php.ini editable there.

I checked php.ini

here have this code

```
;extension=php_soap.dll
```

> [soap]
> ; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
> ; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-enabled
> soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
>
> ; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
> ; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-dir
> soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
>
> ; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used
> ; instead of original one.
> ; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-ttl
> soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
>
> ; Sets the size of the cache limit. (Max. number of WSDL files to cache)
> soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5

Does anyone has the same problem and manage to solved it?

Comment: Whatever "not supported" means, but even if the extension is installed, the extension itself is commented in the php.ini. Maybe you can use dl (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php). You need to have the extension installed anyways. Otherwise, if the extension can't be used, you need to use a php library instead of the extension and change your code.